# Android ensure HTTP response arrives

Tags: java, android, rest, android-studio, okhttp

I am making a synchronous HTTP request and before my response arrives my UI loads and there is nothing to show.

How can I handle this?

I am using an expandable list and it is being populated using an okHTTP request.

Comment: Show some work and narrow your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using ListView,RecyclerView etc then you can refresh your ListView or RecyclerView by

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

adapter is an custom component to plot on ListView or RecyclerView ( ViewHolder)

if you have are not using this then you can't use synchronous call ,  you have to make an asynchronous call. after successful asynchronous call assign the values to UI components like textview,editext etc.

Comment: thank you but where should I call it? I mean which call back? onStart(), onCreateView()? (I am on a Fragment) I am calling the api and setting adapters onCreateView

Comment: at the end of api call where your collection i.e. arraylist,list etc getting formed.

Comment: Thanks man but it's not working. I am placing it in onCreateView once The call commences but still adapter doe not refresh. Any suggestions?